# pandas - keep only those columns name in my df which are common in df.index & df.columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df where index and column names are 6 digit postal codes,125 postal codes are common in both df.index and df.columns, in my df now I want only those 125x125 values . I was able to remove unwanted postal codes from index by using the following piece of code

```
df = df[df.index.isin(df.columns)]
```

but for columns when I am using the same kind of code

```
df = df[df.columns.isin(df.index)]
```

its throwing error

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 813 elements, new values have 125 elements
```

Can you guys help me with this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For filtering by columns use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `:` for get all rows and mask for filter columns names:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(df.index)]
```